# Selenium 2: New Browser Has No Bookmarks

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, selenium, selenium-webdriver

When I use Selenium 2 code (Java) to open Firefox (or any other browser) for some automated tests, the new window opens without my bookmarks, or for that matter the bookmark bar. Additionally, I suspect that cookies aren't retrieved either, because sites I normally log into do not remember certain things from my previous history.

The relevant code:

```
//WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
String baseUrl = "http://localhost:8080/";
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

//Navigate to login page
driver.navigate().to(baseUrl + "/myApp");

//obtain the username and password elements
WebElement username = driver.findElement(By.name("username"));
WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.name("password"));

//log in
username.sendKeys("myTestLogin");
password.sendKeys("myTestPwd");
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.btnStyle")).click();
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think by default Selenium (WebDriver) will try to use as "clean" of a profile as possible.  This is so the browser's settings that a user set up don't cause testing failures.  You can modify these settings if you need to.  Check out http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/TipsAndTricks and see if that helps get you on the right track.  I haven't done this with IE before though.  I think with Firefox you can even have Selenium use an existing profile if you really need it to.

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful, and I was able to successfully load the Firefox profile. However, my main problem has not gone away. My J2EE app includes an applet that runs upon sign on, and reads a local directory. It is unable to do so now... Why would that be?

Comment: It's been a long time since I did anything with applets so I don't have any help specifically for that but my general pattern for debugging issues with a selenium test is to start it up and use a breakpoint to pause the test before the problem starts. Then I just interact with the browser directly. Maybe you'll be able to see what's happening with the browser or applet to cause the issue? Sorry I can't be of more help with this one.